# Remember Scroll positions for inflated layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two button in linear layout(works as a tab) . I am inflecting two layoutson click of eighter butttons. these inflated layouts i am adding in main layout which has scrollview as parent. now when i click on 1st tab and scroll down and click on 2nd tab , Second tab data also getting scrolled.  any one having solution on this?

Comment: Please revise this question. This is unintelligible.

Comment: how to remember scroll position for inflated layouts in android?

Comment: Better try SharedPreference to save scroll position